# Passing list<string> to a function

Tags: asp.net, list, function, session

I have a session variable that i create dynamically, so lets say for instance i have the following session variables

```
Session["area1"]
Session["area2"]
Session["area3"]
Session["area4"]
```

And in each of those sessions i have a List in there

then i have this in order to get what the name will be and use it in my code

```
string areaName = "area" + Session["area"];
```

Session["area"] is a session variable that increases it self based on how many times a button is clicked

Now if i try to pass areaName to a function that is requiring a List as a parameter it doesn't let me do it, even though the value in that session variable is a list

I am only using "areaName" to be able to get the name of the session

How can i use it in order to pass it to function that is requiring a List type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling the following:

```
string areaName = "area" + Session["area"];
```

You are saying, take the string "area", and append to that the variable from Session (which is an object by default), which will call it's ToString() method. Your end result here, is a string, not a list. (And not a meaningful one at that).

All you need to do is take the Session value, and cast it to the type that you know it is.

```
method((List<string>)Session["area"])
```

or

```
method(Session["area"] as List<string>)
```

The reason you can't just pass in Session["area"] without first casting, is because session returns your variable as an object. Sure, it may be a list in memory, but the system treats it the same as any other object (Look up [Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) for more info), which is not the List that it expects. Thus, you will get a compile time error, unless you cast it to the correct type.

Comment: *Only* use the form with `as` if (1) there is a chance it might not be a `List<string>` after all, and (2) you can use (or react to) a `null` value in that case. If those criteria are not met, use the other syntax.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - I believe in the converse of your statement, only use the `(List<string>)` cast syntax if you are "sure" that the `Session` object contains a `List<string>`; otherwise an exception will be thrown. Also, I believe defensive programming accounts for `null`.

Comment: I need to use the areaName because i don't know which session it will pick up because they are dynamic, so thats why i created the string areaName just to be able to get the name of the session it will use at that moment

Answer (score 2):

If you know it contains a list, then do the cast. For instance

```
myMethod(Session["area1"] as List<string>);
```

Comment: Using the `as` syntax gives the added benefit of not generating an exception if the cast fails, because the `List<string>` will be null and still passed to the method. Just make sure to check if the list is null before using it in the method called.

Comment: Agree with Karl. Don't use `as` if you know the type is good. Only use `as` if you are going to check for `null` immediately after.

Comment: that's whats happening now, i can see that when i cast it as a list its null, but when i try to print out the values of the session[areaName] i can get all the values no problem

Comment: @user2593590: For sure your cast is incorrect. what is the exact type of this list? Try with `IList<string>`